# Remove list style images

Tags: html, css

I thought I knew this, but I finding it really hard to remove list style images. Let's take

[links removed]

as an example. I want to remove the arrows you can see on the right side there. I tried the following:

```
#rightCol ul,#rightCol li,#rightCol ul li{list-style:none;}
#rightCol ul,#rightCol li,#rightCol ul li{background-image:none;}
```

I'm using background image to create the arrow in the first place, but can't really get it away. Any suggestion? (above is a test, for my purpose it will be #rightCol .nolists... )

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the li element has a background, So you need to do:

```
#rightCol .moduletable ul li{
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! that worked.. I thought background-image was enough.. thanks again for the swift reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

`background-image:none` worked fine for me. Have you tried refreshing your cache?

**EDIT:** 
Ah yeah, the difference is, your style is less specific than the one used to put the background image on so it's getting overwritten, which includes `.moduletable`.

```
#rightCol .moduletable ul li {
   background-image:none;
}
```

Should do the trick.

CSS prioritises based on specificity as well as where the style appears compared to others. If you have two styles of the *same* specificity, the later one will overwrite properties from the earlier one, but if the earlier one is *more* specific, it will take precedence.